# Using TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND wireless routers USB Printer under linux

Tags: printing

I have a TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND v3 wireless router into which one can plug an USB Printer. Under windows there is a TP link Software with which the printer can be used.
Under ubuntu I have no Idea. The printer is not detected as a network printer.

Is there any way I can use the printer from my ubuntu computer?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [TP-Link's site.](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-352.html) (Start at step 5) - This is for a different router, but it may work for yours as well.

Quick summary of what it says:

1. Add a new printer
2. Select LPD/LPR Host or Printer
3. Type IP address of your router
4. Choose the driver of the printer (you may have to install the driver, or test if the drivers are available by plugging the printer into your ubuntu computer)
5. Give it a name and press Apply

Comment: No, it does not work. I also think that link refers to a pure printserver, not a router with printer sharing. One would hope, that the mechanism is the same. But it does not work :-(.

Comment: It does work. But it also depends on a printer. You may probably need to install a printer driver. What is your printer?

Comment: It is a ML-2010, it works if I directly connect it to my computer. Under windows it works with the TP-LINK software (see here: http://www.tp-link.de/FAQ-415.html)

Comment: @Nathan As Pilot6 mentioned, there is the option of going with OpenWRT. And digging a little more, it seems TP-Link does not support printing from Linux with their routers and their firmware. You may have to switch firmware to enable that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

System Settings -> Printers -> Add new printer.

Network Printer -> Appsocket/HP JetDirect

Enter your router IP address as "server".

Keep "9100" as port.

Depending on your printer model you may need to install a printer driver.

I use routers as print servers a lot. It should work.

At least it works this way with Openwrt firmware with `p910nd` installed.

Comment: Using this, I also get "The printer is not responding.". Under Windows the printer works :-(

Comment: Does it work on Windows?

Comment: And what is your printer model?

Comment: It is a Samsung ML-2010 and it works under windows using the TP Link software.

Comment: Did you install a printer driver to Ubuntu?

Comment: Well, I choose the printer driver when installing. And it works when I connect the printer directly to my computers USB port.

Comment: Actually I do not know how print server is set up in the Stock Tp-link Firmware. I use Openwrt and it works there this way all times when a printer is supported.

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to avoid this because I am afraid of bricking  the router. But if it is the only option ...